# Unity android manifest FPS boost

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, manifest

I am developing a GPS location game (using Mapbox, firebase). I am getting about 50 fps average ingame, 30 fps when UI (canvas) is opened.
Today I downloaded some AndroidManifest with `unityShowAndroidStatusBar.aar`, that should make the android status bar visible. I copyied it to `Assets/Plugins/Android`. Now what happened, when I build it with this manifest in, I get almost in every moment 60 fps.
This is the manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<manifest xmlns:android="[http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android](http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android)" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="com.company.productname">
  <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
  <application android:icon="@drawable/app\_icon" android:label="[@String](https://forum.unity.com/members/7078/)/app\_name" android:theme="[@StyLe](https://forum.unity.com/members/863766/)/UnityTransparentStatusBarTheme">
    <activity android:label="[@String](https://forum.unity.com/members/7078/)/app\_name" android:name="com.unity3d.nostatusbar.UnityPlayerActivityStatusBar"> 
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK\_LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
      <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.UnityActivity" android:value="true" />
    </activity>
  </application>
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9" android:targetSdkVersion="23" />
</manifest>
```

Since I don't understand these android things at all yet, can someone explain me, what could lead to that high fps boost? The manifest without this from unity looks similar, just without the transparent status bar thing.

Comment: interesting one. Do you have the sourcecode of the `unityShowAndroidStatusBar.aar`?

Comment: https://github.com/Over17/UnityShowAndroidStatusBar

here is it.

Comment: there is nothing obvious in the code. do you use the same device? what happens if you remove the plugin?

Comment: Same device. If I remove, back to 45 fps avg. If I add again, back to 60 fps.

Comment: I'm almost out of ideas. What happens if you set the framerate to 60 fps in code like this: `Application.targetFrameRate = 60;` with removed plugin?

Comment: I tried it already. Keeps at 45.

Comment: I forget to mention one, maybe important thing, actualy. Without this magic manifest, I could get the same high framerate by minimalizing (tabbing to desktop) and then tabbing back to the game. THen I get same high framerate, but only for few seconds. Then it drops back.